# Convert double to string with n decimal places without trailing zeros

Tags: c++, c

1)`double d = 1.234567899;`
Convert this number to string with 8 decimal places without truncation.
So,expected output is "1.23456789", truncating last 9.

and

2)`if d = 1.2345699;`
so Solution should not append 0 upto 8th decimal place.expected output "1.2345699".

I have tried many solutions,ended up with stringstream c++ class. 2nd problem is solved but first one still persist.

Is there any way to achieve the output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sprintf(str, "%1.8f", d);

Comment: Are you sure you want 1.23456789 and not 1.2345679? The latter is the proper way to round your number.

Comment: @n.m. yes.. this is the requirement

Comment: @OlegOlivson it results in 1.23456790

Comment: @user2798564 if you round this value to 8 digits after dot you'll get exactly this value, if you want to truncate last 9, you'll miss 0.000000009 from your initial value, not 0.000000001 when you round it

Comment: to simply truncate - multiply it to 100000000, save as int and then divide it to 100000000 value and save as double

Answer (score 2):

If you want to truncate part of the string representation without rounding, you need to do that manually:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
        std::stringstream s;
        double d = 1.234567899;

        // print it into sstream using maximum precision
        s << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10) << 1.234567899;
        std::string res = s.str();

        // Now the res contains something like 1.234567899000000
        // so truncate 9000000000 by hand

        size_t dotIndex = res.find(".");

        std::string final_res = res.substr(0, dotIndex + 9);

        std::cout << final_res << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way.and this will break my second case.

Comment: How will this break your second case? Move the code from the main to the function which will receive one double, number of the digits after period and which will return string.

Comment: there is a workaround to take size difference between . and lenght of string.Then i can create string upto 8 decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be served by first Flooring the double to the required decimals?
If so, have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/3600/

Answer (score 0):

Truncating exactly as you want:

```
sprintf(str, "%1.10f", d);
memset(str+10, 0x00, 1);
```