# C++ Only output one decimal place

Tags: c++

I have a float that I've set to 4.5, but when I render it to the screen it shows 4.500000. I've tried googling and searching stackoverflow, but all of the answers use printf() or std::cout which I can't use since I don't want to output it to the console. Sorry for the nooby question, here's the code:

```
TextRenderer::render(*window, std::to_string(player->health) + " HP", sf::Vector2f(3, 0), 16, sf::Color(155, 0, 0));
```

EDIT: TextRenderer.cpp

```
#include "TextRenderer.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include "Logger.h"

sf::Font TextRenderer::kavoon = sf::Font();

TextRenderer::TextRenderer()
{
}

TextRenderer::~TextRenderer()
{
}

bool TextRenderer::load() {
    if (!TextRenderer::kavoon.loadFromFile("data/fonts/kavoon.ttf"))
    {
        Logger::error("Couldn't load kavoon font.");
    }
    return true;
}

void TextRenderer::render(sf::RenderWindow& window, std::string string, sf::Vector2f position, int size, sf::Color color) {
    sf::Text text;

    text.setFont(TextRenderer::kavoon);
    text.setString(string);

    text.setPosition(position);

    text.setCharacterSize(size);
    text.setColor(color);

    window.draw(text);
}
```

Comment: That depends on what `TextRenderer` is, what is `TextRenderer`?

Comment: Try looking at sprintf, which is the same as printf but instead of printing to the screen it outputs to a `char*`

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18913780/10077

Comment: Take a look at `std::stringstream` which allows formatted output to a `std::string`.

Comment: In addition to Thomas Matthews comment, take a look at std::setprecision, which allows you to manipulate decimal precision in streams.

Comment: A `float` likely has 23 bits of precision, so it won't ever store `4.5` using just 4 bits. The other 19 bits will be present and will be 0, thus the value in memory is in fact `4.500000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ostringstream to do this.

```
ostringstream ss;
ss << player->health;
string health = ss.str();
```

and then

```
TextRenderer::render(*window, health + " HP", sf::Vector2f(3, 0), 16, sf::Color(155, 0, 0));
```